# Jdk 8 install problem?I am using ubuntu 17.10 version

Tags: java

When I run this command:

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

then the error occurs:

```
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information, like what installer you're using, where you got it, what command you used to run it, and what version of Ubuntu you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Comment: Please also leave a little explenation not only a command line.